# vim advice on getting around

Tags: visual-studio, vim, text-editor, key-bindings

I have been using vim for a few days now and I really like the key bindings and the separate modes. I would really like to be able to be a little more efficient when using the various shortcuts etc.. that it has to offer.

For example I got a vim extension for visual studio and I had this line of code:

```
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
```

I wanted to get into the braces so I tried 5W, this took me to the first brace, then I pressed 'L' to go in and 'I' to go into insert mode.

I don't feel that I am using it to its potential, does anyone have any suggestions as to a quicker way they would have done that? or suggest things that I can look at to get even more efficient at editing using what vim has to offer, I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your cursor is before the `()` on that line, you can try pressing:

```
%i
```

I think it would be the best way to go there. Of course you could do this as well:

```
f(a
```

to the question "how to get more productive"

- think about those operations, you thought "complex/not productive" (like the one in your question)
- try to find out a better solution by google/vim help/doc
- use the new solution in your daily edit
- if you cannot find better solution, ask here or other vim community, like vim-use mailing list.

Comment: Yes, those are definitely more productive and less complex ways to do it! awesome! I'll have to get more comfortable with the key bindings I guess, I am in a sort of transition stage where it is new but I am starting to get a good feel for it. Thank you or the answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Those two cheat-sheets will get you pretty far:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If there is a way to accept more than one answer please tell me, because this is an awesome sheet!

Comment: not possible to have more than one accepted answer, but once you have more than 15 reptuation points you can upvoate answers